# Unable to find “haar classifiers” for nose ,ear and classifiers for the side view of a face

Tags: opencv, face-detection, haar-classifier

i am working on an Android application that detect the body parts of face like mouth , eye , ear and nose and from the sideview i need to detect the ear eye and mouth too

i am able to complete the detection of eyes , mouth from the front view but unable to detect the nose and ear ..

i have followed the following github project and expermient different clasifier files from it 
[enter link description here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades) github link for open cv project

if anyone has worked on the detection of ear and nose or worked with the face detection from the sideview using open cv in android/iOS and can share what classifiers used for it that woulb be a great help for me

Comment: you could try to train your own ones (and share them if it works)

Comment: There's no pre-trained classifier for nose and ears. You can train your own following the [OpenCV tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d88/tutorial_traincascade.html#gsc.tab=0). Or you may want to use something like face landamarks recognition, like [this](http://www.csc.kth.se/~vahidk/face_ert.html)

Comment: well i did find the nose classifier file from this link 
http://sourceforge.net/p/emgucv/opencv/ci/b7553d4e2eddc5645023a94a850fe092dd9f223e/tree/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_mcs_nose.xml

but i checked it does not work 
and the the method to create your own classifier you shared is good but it is very lengthy i don't have that much time for now

Answer (score 1):

I have found many locations on the web creating have classifieds. I have a consolidated view in my iOS project eyes2drive [haarclassifier in my github](https://github.com/lolo8304/focusdays2015-eyes2drive)

- iOS subproject eyes2drive

I have tested many. Some of them need a big range of face. Others are perfectly using a part of the face (eyes classifier)

Side detection of eyes and nose is not working with haarclassifiers.

There are many many haarclassifiers around: try them but be aware of that the minsize, neighbors  and other options are also important

I have developed a few debug options while capturing and detection to see the best results. You can use my project to see. 
Before you change too often classifieds please test the best options for your use case. [image: see debug options bottom of screen]
[image: and visualization with debugging]

Comment: thanks @Lorenz for sharing your experience with me but exactly what i need is the working classifiers for the sideview  of a face , front classifiers are working well in my application